# How to change *default* open-file limit on Ubuntu 12.4

Tags: azure, ubuntu-12.04, ulimit

We have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS servers, both local and hosted in Azure.
While we can change the file limits for interactively logged in users, it seems that by default, services started by init.d get a hard open-file limit of 4096.  While we can use upstart and set higher limits for specific services, this doesn't help us for, say, Hortonworks HDP, which runs all sorts of services using its own mechanisms.  What I want is to change the system-wide default open-file limit for *everything*.  How do we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. check system wide settings: /etc/security/limits.conf**

A very no limitations config file:

```
*               soft    nofile  102400
*               hard    nofile  102400
*               soft    nproc   102400
*               hard    nproc   102400
root            hard    nofile  102400
root            soft    nofile  102400
```

**2. check program auto startup script and its settings**

**program auto startup script** is a bit different, it has its own settings, or it will use **the default 1024**.

Example: program supervisor(Test on Ubuntu 12/14)

```
/etc/init.d/supervisor - auto startup script
/etc/init/supervisor.conf - auto startup script settings
```

You can add **ulimit** command in **/etc/init.d/supervisor** to set the limits, or just add limits settings in **/etc/init/supervisor.conf**. **/etc/init/supervisor.conf** example:

```
limit nofile 102400 102400
```

**3. check program specific settings**

Some program has its own limits. Like supervisor, it has its own file/process limits, so you must also add **minfds** and **minprocs** settings on its config files **/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf**. Some other program just use the system or auto startup settings.